# should all/most awt.Toolkit methods be run in the EDT?

Tags: java, clipboard, toolkit, edt

... specifically, I'm using getSystemClipboard()... and then doing things like getting and setting content.

At the start of the API doc (Java 7) it says:

> Many GUI events may be delivered to user asynchronously, if the
>   opposite is not specified explicitly. As well as many GUI operations
>   may be performed asynchronously. This fact means that if the state of
>   a component is set, and then the state immediately queried, the
>   returned value may not yet reflect the requested change.

... I'm not at all clear how this relates to whether or not Toolkit's methods (and clipboard's) should be run in the EDT...!

Comment: Clipboard methods are synchronized where necessary, so its safe to call them from any thread. *But* this is not explicitly documented, I only found out by looking at the source code.

Comment: thanks... useful info